# maximum value of $ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, factoring, maxima-minima

If $a,b\in R$ and $\displaystyle a^2+b^2=1+\frac{2ab}{a-b}$  and $\sqrt{a-b}=a^2+5b$, what is the maximum of $ab$?

Here is what I tried:

$a=r\cos\alpha$ and $b=r\sin \alpha$

$\displaystyle r^2=1+\frac{r\sin 2\alpha}{\cos \alpha-\sin \alpha}$

and $\sqrt{r(\cos \alpha-\sin \alpha)}=r^2\cos^2\alpha+5r\sin \alpha$

Comment: note that the variables are not given to vary as you assume

Comment: Note the assumption $a=r\cos\alpha$ and $b=r\sin \alpha$ is invalid since max $ab=\frac{r\sin 2\alpha}{2}$ means $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $r^2=1+\frac{r\sin 2\alpha}{\cos \alpha-\sin \alpha}$ has singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain gives $a-b>0$ and from the first equation we obtain:
$$(a-b)^2+2ab=1+\frac{2ab}{a-b}$$ or
$$(a-b)^2-1+2ab\left(1-\frac{1}{a-b}\right)=0$$ or
$$(a-b-1)\left(a-b+1+\frac{2ab}{a-b}\right)=0$$ or
$$a=b+1.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the following answer: $42$.

Comment: why $\displaystyle a-b+1+\frac{2ab}{a-b}\neq 0$ explain it please

Comment: jacky Because $1+\frac{2ab}{a-b}=a^2+b^2>0$ and $a-b>0$.